# AJAX not working in select fields - UPDATED

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've made a form with two select fields. The first field is populated with the parents of a custom taxonomy. The second field is populated with the children of each one. I used AJAX to do that but does not seem to work. Nothing happens on change.

Below is my PHP code:

```
function products_selection()
{
    $args = array(
      'post_type'   => 'seller',
      'taxonomy'    => 'category',
      'hide_empty'  => 0,
      'exclude'     => 1,1078,1079
    );
    $products = get_categories( $args );

    if ( $products ) {
    echo '<select id="products-select">';
      echo '<option selected="" disabled="" value="0"><span>Προϊόντα</span></option>';

      foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo '<option class="product-name" id="'. $product->term_id .'">'. $product->name .'</option>';
      }
    echo '</select>';
  }
}

function nomoi()
{
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'seller',
    'taxonomy'  => 'nomos',
    'hide_empty'=> 0,
    'parent'    => 0
  );

  $categories = get_categories( $args );

  if ( $categories ) {
    echo '<select id="nomoi-select">';
      echo '<option selected="0" value="-1"><span>Νομοί</span></option>';

      foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        $id = $category->term_id;
        $name = $category->name;
        $taxonomy = $category->taxonomy;
        echo '<option class="nomos" id="'. $id .'">'. $name .'</option>';
      }
    echo '</select>';
  }

  echo '<select id="town-select">';
    echo '<option selected="" disabled="" value="0"><span>Πόλεις</span></option>';
  echo '</select>';
}

function my_ajax() {
  if(isset($_POST['main_catid']))
    {
      $args = array(
        'order_by' => 'name',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'exclude' => 1,
        'taxonomy' => 'nomos',
        'name' => 'town-select',
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => 'Πόλεις',
        'selected' => -1,
        'child_of' => $_POST['main_catid'],
        'echo' => 1
      );
    $categories =  get_categories( $args );
    foreach ( $categories as $cat ) {
      $cat_name = $cat->name;
      $id = $cat->cat_ID;
      echo '<option class="town" id="'. $category->id .'">'. $category->name .'</option>';
    }
  die();
  } // end if
}
```

My script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // Avoid conflicts
        $ = jQuery;

        $('#nomoi-select').change(function() {

            $mainCat = $('#nomoi-select option:selected').attr('id');
            console.log('$mainCat: ' + $mainCat);

            // call ajax
            $("#town-select").empty();
            $.ajax
            (
                {
                    url:'index.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    // Use an object literal
                    data: {
                        "action" : "my_ajax()",
                        "main_catid" : $mainCat
                    },

                    success:function( results )
                    {
                        //  alert(results);
                         alert('Successfully called');
                        $("#town-select").append( results );
                    },

                    error:function( exception )
                    {
                        alert('Exception: ' + exception);
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    });
```

And the function to register my script:

```
function my_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'header-form', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/headerform.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Comment: `#main_cat` is a select? Then use `var $mainCat=$('#main_cat option:selected').val();` to get the value of the selected option.

Comment: No luck. Is it because it's inside a form or something?

Comment: What does the console say when you log `$mainCat`? ( `console.log($mainCat)` )

Comment: ReferenceError: $mainCat is not defined

Comment: Well, that's your problem... and when you use `var $mainCat=$('#main_cat option:selected').val();`. Can you add the rendered HTML of `#main_cat` to your question aswell?

Comment: main_cat is defined through  wp_dropdown_categories( $args ) from wordpress. I've posted some of the output

Comment: And what does the console say when you use: `var $mainCat=$('#main_cat option:selected').val(); console.log( $mainCat);`

Comment: undefined. and I've changed the option too.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a JSFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vageliskatsiotis/97r1tvxx/

Comment: I've update the jsfiddle. Is it possible for you to take a look? Thanxs in advance!!

Comment: The line `var $mainCat=$('#main_cat option:selected').val();` does it's work (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/97r1tvxx/6/)). There is probably something wrong in the AJAX request (or its page). Try setting the error, see what error comes out (Documentation can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with WordPress, I suspect you could be having jQuery conflict issues. To confirm this, you can try changing all instances of `$` to `jQuery` and see if you get the same errors.

Also - if you are running this script from a `.js` file, the PHP wont evaluate, but keeping the URL relative should still work fine.

I have made a few changes to the script which you can try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Avoid conflicts
    $ = jQuery;

    $('#main_cat').change(function() {

        $mainCat = $('#main_cat option:selected').val();

        // call ajax
        $("#sub_cat").empty();
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url:"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                type:'POST',
                // Use an object literal
                data: {
                  "action" : "my_ajax",
                  "main_catid" : $mainCat
                },

                success:function( results )
                {
                    //  alert(results);
                    $("#sub_cat").removeAttr("disabled").append( results );
                }
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: although the second select is not being populated, it does not even gets enabled and that gets me to think that there is something wrong with js..No luck M.Doye. Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From the fiddle you provided, simply adding `console.log('$mainCat: ' + $mainCat);` (see [this modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97r1tvxx/5/)) ensures that the `change` event fires as expected.
Beyond that we get a `404 not found` error, which is pretty normal in the current state of the fiddle example.

So it is certain that your issue comes from something with the Ajax called script or its returned data.

You only said that "Nothing happens on change", without any precision. In fact you should now use Firebug or similar to look at error messages, which may be, either:

- an URL generation error: in this case you should get a `404 not found` error too
- an error in the server script you're invoking: in this case you should get a `500 server error` error
- a bad (malformed) return from the server: in this case you should get a JS error

Also note that:

- it cannot be an empty return from the server, or your `#sub_cat` element would have already lost its `disabled` attribute before a JS error happens
- at the opposite (even if unlikely) it also might be an Ajax error: so to be sure you should add an `error:` or `always:` member to the `$.ajax()` argument

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've debugged the page using Firebug and got 404 Not Found error. Is it because I'm using locally developing?

Comment: I've posted the firebug output. Changed the url to "ajaxurl" to get response.

Comment: I don't understand: you said "I've posted the firebug output." but I don't see anything like that. In the other hand, you confirmed you get a `404 not found` error, so you should now focus on it: carefully control the way you declare and register your own plugin. I noticed that the URL in your first post differs from the one in your fiddle, and moreover I don't know WP: so I can't say more about that. Sorry.

Comment: I've deleted it because I've got the ajax working but cannot get the results I want. Thanx for your help